# Access port of one container from another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network, docker-link

I have a postgres database in one container, and a java application in another container. Postgres database is accessible from port 1310 in localhost, but the java container is not able to access it.
I tried this command:

```
docker run modelpolisher_java java -jar ModelPolisher-noDB-1.7.jar --host=biggdb --port=5432 --user=postgres --passwd=postgres --dbname=bigg
```

But it gives error `java.net.UnknownHostException: biggdb`.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  biggdb:
    container_name: modelpolisher_biggdb
    build: ./docker/bigg_docker
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=bigg
    ports:
      - "1310:5432"
  java:
    container_name: modelpolisher_java
    build: ./docker/java_docker
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Dockerfile for biggdb:

```
FROM postgres:11.4

RUN apt update &&\
apt install wget -y &&\
# Create directory '/bigg_database_dump/' and download bigg_database dump as 'database.dump'
wget -P /bigg_database_dump/ https://modelpolisher.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bigg_database.dump &&\
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./scripts/restore_biggdb.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/restore_biggdb.sh

EXPOSE 1310:5432
```

Can somebody please tell what changes I need to do in the docker-compose.yml, or in the command, to make java container access ports of biggdb (postgres) container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385977/accessing-a-docker-container-from-another-another-container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing a docker container from another another container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385977/accessing-a-docker-container-from-another-another-container)

Answer (score 1):

The two containers have to be on the same Docker-internal network to be able to talk to each other.  [Docker Compose automatically creates a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and attaches containers to that network.  If you're `docker run` a container alongside that, you need to find that network's name.

Run

```
docker network ls
```

This will list the Docker-internal networks you have.  One of them will be named something like `bigg_default`, where the first part is (probably) your current directory name.  Then when you actually run the container, you can attach to that network with

```
docker run --net bigg_default ...
```

Consider setting a [`command:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) in your `docker-compose.yml` file to pass these arguments when you `docker-compose up`.  If the `--host` option is your code and doesn't come from a framework, passing settings like this via environment variables can be a little easier to manage than command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As you use `docker-compose` to bring up the two containers, they already share a common network. To be able to access that you should use `docker-compose run` and not `docker run`. Also, pass the service name (`java`) and not the container name (`modelpolisher_java`) in `docker-compose run` command.

So just use the following command to run your jar:

```
docker-compose run java java -jar ModelPolisher-noDB-1.7.jar --host=biggdb --port=5432 --user=postgres --passwd=postgres --dbname=bigg
```