# Docker : Accessing another container by host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, network-programming

I have two containers defined in a docker-compose yaml file that need to talk to each other, but they can't.

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  localdev:
    driver: 'bridge'

services:
  master-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: master-db
    hostname: master-db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4000:3306"
    networks:
      - localdev

  page-store:
    hostname: page-store
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.page_store
    container_name: page-store
    ports:
      - "2020:2020"
    networks:
      - localdev
    links:
      - master-db
```

In the page-store Python Flask microservice, I try to access the MySQL database by using its hostname of master-db, but the name cannot resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to connect each other using respective service names. `master-db` and `page-store` removing `hostname`

As per [Official guide](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) you may have to define `master-db`,`page-store` in container's `/etc/hosts`, if you want to use `hostname: page-store` etc.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385977/accessing-a-docker-container-from-another-container) SO thread.

Also using [--links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) may not be the best option.

Comment: Removing the --links and hostnames seemed to be the answer, thank you