# Docker Max retries exceeded with url: /assets

Tags: python, docker, networking

I'm a bit new to docker and I'm messing around with it. I currently have a server being ran on port `5000` in another container. This server is being ran with express and uses JavaScript. I'm trying to send requests to that server with python. I tried using both `localhost:5000` and `127.0.0.1:5000` but neither of these seems to work. What can I do? I noticed if I run the python code without docker it works perfectly fine.

Python Docker File:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3 -y 
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

WORKDIR /usr/app/src
COPY . .

RUN pip install discum
RUN pip install python-dotenv

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python3", "./src/index.py"]
```

JavaScript Docker File:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a network between the to containers using --net look at this answer [How to get Docker containers to talk to each other while running on my local host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093812/how-to-get-docker-containers-to-talk-to-each-other-while-running-on-my-local-hos)

Another way, and my preferred way, is to use docker-compose and create networks between your containers.

**EDIT -------**

Sorry, I didn’t see the notification of your question. This is not a video but to get started with the basics of docker-compose I would try something like https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ . For networking multiple containers together you can create simple networks like this https://accesto.com/blog/docker-networks-explained-part-2/.

Here is an example of one of the docker-compose.yml files we use.

```
      version: '3'
  
  # create private networks between containers
  networks:
    data:   # simple networks only need to be named
    management:
  
  volumes:
    postgres-data:
    redis-data:
  
  services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - "7001:80"
      volumes:
        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        - ../project/static:/static
      depends_on:
        - web
      command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
      networks:
        - management  # connect this container to the management network
      links:
        - "web"
  
    db:
      container_name: postgres
      image: postgres:9.6.5
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        - ../data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=userid
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
      networks:
        - data  # connect this container to the data network
  
    web:
      container_name: web1
      image: web_image
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      environment:
        - DEBUG=1
        - DOCKER_CONTAINER="1"
        - DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL=ERROR
      volumes:
        - ../project:/code
        - ./configuration.py:/code/project/configuration.py
      working_dir: /code
      ports:
        - "7000:7000"
      command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:7000"
  
      networks:  # connect this container to both networks
        - data
        - management
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
  
    redis:
      image: redis
      volumes:
        - redis-data:/data
      networks:
        - data  # connect this container to the data network
```

Comment: Hey, so I tried messing around with docker-compose and I still got the same error. I was watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HG6yIjZapSA

Could you possibly give me a video/guide I can watch/read

Answer (score 0):

Use Service Name and Port is always the best.
So if you have a docker file like the below you could use the URL http://client:5000

```
version: 3.8
  services:
     client:
        image: blah
        ports:
          - 5000:5000
```