# read udp: io/timeout in the docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, containers

I have a problem running the docker image. I have a simple application connecting with PostgreSQL and I wrote the Dockerfile and docker-compose file to create the images of this application.

There are two images:

1. test2-app
2. postgres

After running the `docker run -it test2-app`, it gives me this error:

`2024/03/05 05:26:10 dial tcp: lookup postgres on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:39295->192.168.75.8:43: i/o timeout`

I restarted the Docker Desktop but it didn't work.

**Note:** I am using WSL 2 on Windows.

**main.go file**

```
const (
    host     = "postgres"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "password"
    dbname   = "test"
)

func main() {
    connStr := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected to PostgreSQL")
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main .

CMD ["./main"]
```

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: test
```

Comment: `2024/03/05 05:26:10 dial tcp: lookup postgres on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:39295->192.168.75.8:43: i/o timeout` <-- did you modify this message in **any** way?

Comment: Yeah I just changed the IP

Comment: You also changed the port to `:43` which makes no sense.

Comment: The problem is resolved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few issues that I have identified in here.

```
const (
    host     = "postgres"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "password"
    dbname   = "test"
)
```

Since you have hardcoded the credentials, the application won't be able to communicate with the PostgreSQL(unless you have the same credentials that you configured when running the PostgreSQL) when you run it within Docker. The host part needs to be the Docker DNS name.

```
app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    depends_on:
      - db
```

You have set environment variables in the Docker Compose file, but they are not being used within your code.

**Solution**

- update the constants as. Setting up the env variables provide flexibility without changing the code.You can modify the behavior of your application without re-compiling it.

```
const (
    host     =  os.Getenv("POSTGRES_HOST")
    port     = 5432
    user     = os.Getenv("POSTGRES_USER")
    password = os.Getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
    dbname   = os.Getenv("POSTGRES_DB")
)
```

- Pass the host name in docker compose environment variable

```yaml
....
environment:
    - POSTGRES_HOST=db
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    - POSTGRES_DB=test
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated it. Now let's run it again to see if it works.

Comment: this is error that I am getting `2024/03/05 06:19:26 dial tcp: lookup port=5432: no such host`

Comment: Are you running this with `docker-compose up` or  with `docker run` as mentioned in your question?

Comment: It is giving me the success message with docker-compose but no host error message with docker run.

Comment: You may need to use the `network` option if you want two containers to communicate with each other using the `docker run` command.  Hope this helps [How to get Docker containers to talk to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093812/how-to-get-docker-containers-to-talk-to-each-other-while-running-on-my-local-hos)

Comment: Alright, I will look at it. Thank you, for helping me! You got one upvote from my side

Comment: Thank you!. Kindly consider marking the answer as accepted once your problem has been successfully resolved. This will not only express your acknowledgment but also serve as a valuable reference for others encountering a similar challenge in the future. :)