# Cannot find PSQL db inside docker via node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

So I am building a backend server using node and express. It also has a PSQL db which is connected via docker.

My server file, server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const {Pool} = require("pg");
const app = express();

var pool = new Pool({user: "postgres", host: "db", password: "root", port: 5432});

const port = 8080;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("hi");
  var q1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes (recId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, recName VARCHAR(255));";
  var q2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingredients (ingId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, recId INT, ingName VARCHAR(255), FOREIGN KEY (recId) REFERENCES recipes(recId));";
  var q3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS directions (dirId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, recId INT, dirEction VARCHAR(255), FOREIGN KEY (recId) REFERENCES recipes(recId));"; 
  try {
    await pool.query("BEGIN");
    console.log("done");
    await pool.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes (recId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, recName VARCHAR(255));");
    console.log("done2");
    await pool.query("COMMIT");
    res.send("Tables created successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    await pool.query("ROLLBACK");
    console.error("Error creating tables:", error); //TODO: error handling
    res.status(500).send("Error creating tables");
  }
});
app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`Listening on http://0.0.0.0:${port}`);
});
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
```

I run `docker compose up`, this is what I get after `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
7c0db9b61a52   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   backend-db-1
```

I can also run `docker exec -it backend-db-1 psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432` and be inside the psql terminal.

However, when I run `node server` and make a post request using postman on `http://0.0.0.0/8080`, I get on my terminal:

```
 Error.captureStackTrace(err);
          ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
    at ###\backend\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:45:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
\Assignments\a2\a2\backend\server.js:26:2 {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'db'
}

Node.js v18.18.0
```

[redacted personal info with ###]

What I understand is it cannot find my db inside my docker container. Cannot figure out why. Would appreciate any sort of help.

after it runs successfully, I should get "Tables created successfully" be sent from the server.

Comment: Hope [How to get Docker containers to talk to each other while running on my local host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093812/how-to-get-docker-containers-to-talk-to-each-other-while-running-on-my-local-hos) this will help to resolve your problem

Comment: Without running `docker exec` or any local commands, what happens when your application starts up?  Is the same error in the `docker-compose up` output?  Does the `server:` container need to `depends_on: [db]`, maybe with an extended health-check option?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the DB using your machine ?

Comment: Ain't no such thing as a "PSQL db". psql is the command line terminal. [Do you mean Postgres?](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your Pool configuration is wrong.
The `host` needs to point matched hostname.

Error: `getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db`: This part of the error message indicates that an error occurred while attempting to resolve the hostname db using the getaddrinfo system call.

In this case, the hostname `db` could not be resolved because Docker containers by default cannot resolve hostnames of other containers directly.

To resolve hostnames of other containers by their service name.  I updated and assigned each container to address this problem.

##### `server.js`

```js
const express = require("express");
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const app = express();

var pool = new Pool({
    user: "postgres",
    host: "postgres_db", // I updated this part
    database: "postgres",
    password: "root",
    port: 5432,
});

const port = 8080;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("hi");
    var q1 =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes (recId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, recName VARCHAR(255));";
    var q2 =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingredients (ingId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, recId INT, ingName VARCHAR(255), FOREIGN KEY (recId) REFERENCES recipes(recId));";
    var q3 =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS directions (dirId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, recId INT, dirEction VARCHAR(255), FOREIGN KEY (recId) REFERENCES recipes(recId));";
    try {
        await pool.query("BEGIN");
        console.log("done");
        await pool.query(q1);
        await pool.query(q2);
        await pool.query(q3);
        console.log("done2");
        await pool.query("COMMIT");
        res.send("Tables created successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        await pool.query("ROLLBACK");
        console.error("Error creating tables:", error); //TODO: error handling
        res.status(500).send("Error creating tables");
    }
});

app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`Listening on http://0.0.0.0:${port}`);
});
```

##### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install express pg

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

##### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  backend_server:
    container_name: backend_server
    image: myapp:latest   # Specify the image name and tag here
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db

  postgres_db:
    container_name: postgres_db  # <-- This name will pointing by Pool's host
    image: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
```

##### Step build server's docker image

```
docker build -t myapp:latest .
```

[image]

##### Check new docker image is built

```
docker image ls
```

[image]

##### Run docker compose

```
docker compose up -d
```

[image]

##### Checking two containers is running

You can see each container name as assigned in `docker-compose.yml`
`backend_server` and `postgres_db`

```
docker ps -a
```

[image]

##### logging server

```
docker logs -f backend_server
```

[image]

##### Access GET endpoint API

Open thus URL by Browser

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

##### Result

[image]

Server log also display `hi/done/done2` message in log.

[image]

Comment: Why did you change `db` to `postgres_db`? Why wouldn't the former have worked?

Comment: I updated docker-compose.yml the container name should be match by Pool's host. If not can't find where is database.

Comment: Sure, but then why not just use `container_name: db` instead of leading with `host: "postgres_db", // I updated this part`?

Comment: Yes, it also works. If Pool's host matched the service name `db`.  it will works too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BenchVue. Although I get what you are doing, it has lead me to the same dead end with the same error of -3008.

Comment: Can you update your question how to get that 3008 error and  detail error information?