My services don't see each other via Docker Compose, and also don't see PosgreSQL on the local machine. Problem with Keycloak
I have PostgreSQL installed on my local machine on port 5432.
I build several microservices via Docker Compose, but they can't connect to PostgreSQL and one service can't see Keycloak. Tried a bunch of options already and it still doesn't work.
Dockerfile:
FROM eclipse-temurin:21.0.2_13-jdk-jammy as build

ARG JAR_FILE
WORKDIR /build

ADD $JAR_FILE application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract --destination extracted

FROM eclipse-temurin:21.0.2_13-jdk-jammy

RUN addgroup spring-boot-group && adduser --ingroup spring-boot-group spring-boot
USER spring-boot:spring-boot-group
VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /application

COPY --from=build /build/extracted/dependencies .
COPY --from=build /build/extracted/spring-boot-loader .
COPY --from=build /build/extracted/snapshot-dependencies .
COPY --from=build /build/extracted/application .

ENTRYPOINT exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher ${0} ${@}

compose.yaml
name: my-app
services:
  keycloak:
    restart: always
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - './config/keycloak/import:/opt/keycloak/data/import'
    ports:
      - '8083:8080'
    command: start-dev --import-realm
    networks:
      - proxynet
  application:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: my-app/target/my-application-3.0.0-exec.jar
      tags:
        - localhost:5000/my-app/application:3.0.0
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: local
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - proxynet
  service:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: my-app-service/target/my-service-3.0.0-exec.jar
      tags:
        - localhost:5000/my-app/service:3.0.0
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: local
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    networks:
      - proxynet
  adm:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: my-app-adm/target/my-app-adm-3.0.0-exec.jar
      tags:
        - localhost:5000/my-app/adm:3.0.0
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: local
    ports:
      - '8084:8084'
    networks:
      - proxynet

networks:
  proxynet:
    name: custom_network

application-local.yaml from service
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-app
    username: admin
    password: admin
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false

application-local.yaml from adm
server:
  port: 8084

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8083/realms/my-app
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: adm-app
            client-secret: {secret}
            scope:
              - openid
              - edit_data
              - microprofile-jwt

logs from ads (doesn't connect to the keycloak)
2024-05-30 15:42:05 2024-05-30T12:42:05.828Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/app/adm/config/SecurityBeans.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityFilterChain' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotiationStrategy' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientManager' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager]: Factory method 'getAuthorizedClientManager' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8083/realms/my-app"
2024-05-30 15:42:05 2024-05-30T12:42:05.829Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-05-30 15:42:05 2024-05-30T12:42:05.835Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
2024-05-30 15:42:05 
2024-05-30 15:42:05 Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-05-30 15:42:05 2024-05-30T12:42:05.841Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2024-05-30 15:42:05 
2024-05-30 15:42:05 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/app/adm/config/SecurityBeans.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityFilterChain' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotiationStrategy' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientManager' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager]: Factory method 'getAuthorizedClientManager' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8083/realms/my-app"
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[application/:na]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[application/:na]
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[application/:na]
2024-05-30 15:42:05 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotiationStrategy' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientManager' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager]: Factory method 'getAuthorizedClientManager' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8083/realms/my-app"
2024-05-30 15:42:05     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:895) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]

But when running locally (not through Docker) everything works stably and connects
UPDATE
The database problem is solved, however, when solving the Keycloak problem with the replacement method in the Docker Compose file:
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8083/realms/my-app

A new error occurred:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: 
Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: 
Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://keycloak:8083/realms/my-app"


in your  both application-local.yaml files, you are specifying localhost which refers to that container itself. hence not able to connect db or keycloak

@Tarique  Where exactly are the containers referring to themselves?

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Does this answer your question? How to get Docker containers to talk to each other while running on my local host?

@PedroCaires That didn't solve the keycloak problem.

I see that you are already using networking in your docker compose file.
Short answer: You are almost there, you just need to replace your localhost for the service name in docker, and use the exposed ports.
Long answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41101432/10880357, please also see the links.
So, all you need to do is:
application-local.yaml from service
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/my-app


application-local.yaml from adm
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8083/realms/my-app

Remember you local machine localhost and you docker containers localhost are not the same =). Remember to also add your postgres database to the docker network, I don't see it in the file you shared.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http ://keycloak:8083/realms/my-app"


1st issue

consider your application-local.yaml from service: inside your docker container you are using this db connection string: url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-app
Here localhost refers to same docker container. Hence it is not able to connect to database. Since postgres is running on host machine not docker. You need to use host.docker.internal OR host's IP instead of localhost.
So your application-local.yaml from service would look like this from top:
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/my-app


Second issue:
in your application-local.yaml from adm also your are using localhost for connecting to keycloak. Since your are running keycloak in another container, you can simply use container's name to connect to it.

So your application-local.yaml from adm should look like this from top:
server:
  port: 8084

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8083/realms/my-app


3rd issue:
Your compose.yaml is missing version info:

version: '3.8'
name: my-app
services:
  keycloak:

Update

Check Keycloak Status:
Ensure that Keycloak is running and accessible. You can check this by running:

docker-compose up -d keycloak

Then, try to access Keycloak directly from your browser:
http://127.0.0.1:8083/realms/my-app/.well-known/openid-configuration
This should return a JSON configuration for the realm if Keycloak is properly running and the realm exists.
check the Keycloak logs to ensure that it is starting up correctly:
docker-compose logs -f keycloak


Add a healthcheck for keycloak:
Sometimes, the application might start before Keycloak is fully up and running. In such cases, you might need to add a startup delay or a health check to ensure that the application starts only after Keycloak is ready. Here’s an example of adding a simple health check to Keycloak in the docker-compose.yml:

version: '3.8'
services:
  keycloak:
    restart: always
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - './config/keycloak/import:/opt/keycloak/data/import'
    ports:
      - '8083:8080'
    command: start-dev --import-realm
    networks:
      - proxynet
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8080/auth/ || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5



Should adm depends on keycloak?
it makes sense for the adm service (as well as other services like application and service that rely on Keycloak for authentication) to depend on Keycloak. This ensures that Keycloak is up and running before these services start. In Docker Compose, you can specify service dependencies using the depends_on attribute:

adm:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: my-app-adm/target/my-app-adm-3.0.0-exec.jar
      tags:
        - localhost:5000/my-app/adm:3.0.0
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: local
    ports:
      - '8084:8084'
    networks:
      - proxynet
    depends_on:
      - keycloak



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://keycloak:8083/realms/my-app"

Update your question to specify what is solved and which command is giving errors now.

The question has been updated

Check answer for updates.
